# WordPress Remove Filter

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

In WordPress I have a calendar (With the "Events Calendar Plugin"). I want this calendar to be for logged in users only. So I used this code:

```
add_filter( 'tribe_events_pre_get_posts', 'redirect_from_events' );
function redirect_from_events( $query ) {
         // print_r("hey");

  if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    return;
 
  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->get( 'eventDisplay' ) ){
      //print_r("hey");
    return;
  }
  // Look for a page with a slug of "logged-in-users-only".
  $target_page = get_posts( [
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'name' => 'logged-in-users-only'
   ] );
 
  // Use the target page URL if found, else use the home page URL.
  if ( empty( $target_page ) ) {
    $url = get_home_url();
      print_r($url);
  } else {
    $target_page = current( $target_page );
    $url = get_permalink( $target_page->ID );
          print_r($url);

  }
   
  // Redirect!
  wp_safe_redirect( $url );
  exit;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_events', 100 );
function restrict_events( $where_sql ) {
  global $wpdb;
  if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) ) {
    return $where_sql;
  }
  return $wpdb->prepare( " $where_sql AND $wpdb->posts.post_type <> %s ", Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE );
}
```

Now I want to cancel this code. I trued commenting it but it's still working. I am not sure but I think I should use Remove_filter to accomplish this. So I created another snippet:

```
remove_filter( 'tribe_events_pre_get_posts', 'redirect_from_events' );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_events', 100 );
```

But the code is still working somehow. Please assist cancelling this code.